# Could not disable default password generator in Spring Security , even after adding user and password in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am adding spring security to my project. It is generating the default password in the console. I want to disable it. Many discussion says that just add **user.name and user.password** in the application.properties.

But even after adding it, the system still generates an auto password and does not recognize the user name configured.

**Are there any recent changes in Spring Security related to this?**

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.code</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring-Security-V1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Spring-Security-V1</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.security.user.name=demouser
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.user.roles=manager
```

Comment: These application properties are a [Spring Boot feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.security). Your setup seems to work, so I'm not sure why...

Comment: Can you please share more code to debug the issue?